# The server may already be running in another process

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat7

Several ports (8005, 8080) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Can you please tell me what is the problem with Tomcat. I am running it on my Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using tomcat with apache or other engine? If so you would have to change apache or tomcat ports so they do not overlap.

Maybe you start tomcat on system start and then you try to run it from eclipse? Before starting eclipse try to shutdown tomcat server.